# ajax auto complete extender not working right, VB.Net

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-services, autocomplete

I'm trying to use an ajax auto complete extender, but it's not working....
I put a break point on the GetCompanyNames method in the web service, but it doesn't even hit the break point.

Here is my ajax autoextender

```
<asp:TextBox TabIndex="1" ToolTip="* Required - enter the Company name" ID="txtCompanyName"
runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="acCompanyName" TargetControlID="txtCompanyName" ServiceMethod="GetCompanyNames" ServicePath="~/WebServices/AutoComplete.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
EnableCaching="true">
 </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Here is the web service that I created

```
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Web.Services
    Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

    ' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the    following line.
    ' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
    <WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
    <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _ 
    Public Class AutoComplete
        Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetCompanyNames(ByVal prefixTest As String) As String()

    Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext

    Dim company = From c In db.CT_Companies
                  Where c.CompanyName.Contains(prefixTest)
                  Select c.CompanyName

    Return company.ToArray

End Function

    End Class
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong or missing?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx), you're missing the `<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()>` attribute and an integer `count` parameter on your method signature.